# How can i apply LIMIT while fetching row-keys from an hbase table?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, stargate

How can i apply LIMIT while fetching row-keys from an hbase table using Hbase/Stargate method? (Like first n row-keys)

Answer (score 0):

As I know there are no need for fetch limit, you have an API which gives you iterator and you can get as many rows as you like.